# Erreur de segmentation (core dumped) when trying to read txt file in C

Tags: c, fgets

I want to read a pgm file in C language using fgets but i get an error and i don't know which instruction cause it.
Here is my code :

```
FILE* file = NULL;
char chaine[TAILLE_MAX] = "";    
int elts[TAILLE_MAX];        

image = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

if(image != NULL)
{
    int i=0;

    while (fgets(chaine, TAILLE_MAX, file) != NULL)
    {                                                     
        elts[i] = atoi(chaine);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++; 
    }
}
```

It reads until the last line of the file. Here is the output :

```
...
325
326
327
328
329
330
331
332
333
334
335
336
337
338
339
340
341
342
343
344
345
346
347
348
349
350
351
352
353
354
355
356
357
358
359
360
361
362
363
364

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 140ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

The probleme is not the file but i think it's about the fgets function

Comment: Is `TAILLE_MAX` more than `364`?

Comment: You cannot just open a pgm file and start reading. You first need to parse the header. Then you read the _rows_ of pixels and convert each pixel to an int. Please look at http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html

Comment: Yes TAILLE_MAX is more than 1000

Comment: If `TAILLE_MAX` is > 1000, the problem is most likely elsewhere in the part of your code you didn't show here.

Comment: the error isn't in the code you posted. I've run it on a file with some numbers and got good results. It also took way less time than your code. Please separate your code to a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you can also run your code with valgrind to find where the segmentation fault started

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you should drop `atoi` and use `strtol` instead. `atoi` is dangerous as it has to error handling, and is to be regarded as deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The text-based [PGM files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) will contain many values on each line for the pixels. With `pixels[i] = atoi(chaine)` you only convert the *first* of those numbers.

You need to parse or [tokenize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) the lines to get all the pixels.

And of course, you need to make sure that the values you read can fit in the destination integer array, which needs to be `W * H` elements large (where `W` is the image width and `H` is the image height).

And as with all image formats, even text-based such, I really recommend you find a library to handle it for you.

Comment: I get you but particularly in this pgm file pixel values are displayed line by line

Comment: Please can you recommend me a specific library ?!

Comment: @KouamJosiane search for libpgm. At least I installed the Ubuntu package the other day.